# Can't overwrite navigation button UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios

I have a `UICollectionViewController` which acts like a paging, each cell has its own page.
On navigation bar, it always shows "Back".
The following wouldn't change the title.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle: @"Back Button Text"
                               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target: nil action: nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
```

Comment: are you running this code in the parent view controller or in the child?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: when you call `setBackBarButtonItem` you are modifying the back button shown by the controllers you push from this controller, if you want to modify the back button shown by the controller you have to modify the `leftBarButtonItem` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use this code:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
       target:nil
       action:nil];
```

**Note that you need to set this on the view controller that the back button *will point to*.** For example, if `ViewControllerA` pushed `ViewControllerB` onto the nav stack, then you would use this code on `ViewController`**`A`**.